# adding style properties to an alert box

Tags: javascript, alert, confirm

Here's a quick background on what I'm trying to do. I have a contact form on my website, and when the user clicks on 'Submit', I want it to do this:

1. User clicks submit
2. Confirmation box opens, asking user to agree or disagree to the
   disclaimer
3. if agrees = submit form
4. if disagrees = close confirmation box

Here is what I want to know. I don't necessarily want to style the actual alert box, since I know that is not possible, what I want to do is style the text inside the alert box; the "disclaimer". I tried just adding header tags and bold tags to it, but those just generate the text and not the actual styles.

Here's the code I'm using, its just a very simple alert box script.. if you have a better idea, please let me know.

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
<!--
function go_there()
{
var where_to= confirm("DISCLAIMER TEXT WILL GO HERE");
if (where_to== true)
 {
  window.location="http://mcgehee.ace-onecomputers.com/nlphpmail.php";
 }
  else
 {

 }
}
//-->
```

HTML:

```
<button class="button" id="submit" value="send" type="submit" name="submit" onClick="go_there()">Send</button>
```

Also, another issue i'm having with this is that instead of it just closing the dialog box, it still continues the script.

Comment: You can't style text inside an alert box. Why not use a modal dialog? Look on Google there are plenty of them, like [smoke.js](http://ssssnakes.com/smoke/) for example.

Comment: smoke.js only allows me to add another alert though.. how would I make it go to the link i need it to go to?

Comment: @Trisha: Use the callbacks that the plugin provides.

Comment: The smoke.js page has examples of how to code confirmations. Note though that when it says "behaves like a normal confirm()" it is lying: you can't just replace a normal `confirm()` without changing anything else because a normal `confirm()` is a blocking call but the smoke.js equivalent is not. This isn't a bad thing once you understand how to use it - all other custom dialogs work in a similar way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot style alert or confirm box. You have to use DHTML box.

**Using Impromptu**

Try this, I used `jQuery Impromptu` plugin http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/4h8cX/6/

For full code, check out page source on http://fiddle.jshell.net/muthkum/4h8cX/6/show/

**Using smoke.js**

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/8qXsv/3/

**UPDATE:**

Here is the full code using `jQuery Impromptu`

You can see, I've included `jquery-1.8.2.js` and `jquery-impromptu.4.0.min.js`. Also styles are included in the below codes. I hope this helps.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo by muthkum</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js'></script>    

      <script type='text/javascript' src="http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/scripts/jquery-impromptu.4.0.min.js"></script>


  <style type='text/css'>
    /*
------------------------------
    Impromptu
------------------------------
*/
.jqifade{
    position: absolute; 
    background-color: #777777; 
}
div.jqi{ 
    width: 400px; 
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    position: absolute; 
    background-color: #ffffff; 
    font-size: 11px; 
    text-align: left; 
    border: solid 1px #eeeeee;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 7px;
}
div.jqi .jqicontainer{ 
    font-weight: bold; 
}
div.jqi .jqiclose{ 
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px; right: -2px; 
    width: 18px; 
    cursor: default; 
    color: #bbbbbb; 
    font-weight: bold; 
}
div.jqi .jqimessage{ 
    padding: 10px; 
    line-height: 20px; 
    color: #444444; 
}
div.jqi .jqibuttons{ 
    text-align: right; 
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0; 
    border: solid 1px #eeeeee; 
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
div.jqi button{ 
    padding: 3px 10px; 
    margin: 0 10px; 
    background-color: #2F6073; 
    border: solid 1px #f4f4f4; 
    color: #ffffff; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-size: 12px; 
}
div.jqi button:hover{ 
    background-color: #728A8C;
}
div.jqi button.jqidefaultbutton{
    background-color: #BF5E26;
}
.jqiwarning .jqi .jqibuttons{ 
    background-color: #BF5E26;
}


  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

function go_there(){

    $.prompt('<b>DISCLAIMER</b> <span style="font-weight:normal">TEXT WILL GO HERE</span>',{
       buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false}, 
       callback: function(e,v,m,f){
          if(v){
             window.location="http://mcgehee.ace-onecomputers.com/nlphpmail.php";
          }else{

          }
       }
   });

}

//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <button class="button" id="submit" value="send" type="submit" name="submit" onClick="go_there()">Send</button>


</body>


</html>

​
```

Comment: @elclanrs: I don't know what I did wrong, but now its not generating the dialog box at all. link to the site is mcgehee.ace-onecomputers.com. i've tried both the smoke.js 'smoke.confirm', and the way Muthu suggested.

Comment: can you put your code in http://jsfiddle.net and share it to me? So that I can help you.

Comment: You didn't include `jquery.js` and `jquery-impromptu.js` that the reason it's working for you.

Comment: I got the smoke.js to work, but it times out and sends the script after a few seconds.. to see it you have to actually go to the site and submit the form, mcgehee.ace-onecomputers.com (i don't know why it doesn't let me add that as a hyperlink.. weird.)

Comment: Still no fix on why it still loads the form without clicking on ok or cancel.. any help?

Comment: if you are still checking this out, its also doing the same thing with the impromptu script [link here](http://mcgehee.ace-onecomputers.com/test) --- have any ideas as to why it still loads the form before the user can click ok/cancel?

Comment: you don't want the form to appear on the page?

Comment: Muthu, its been resolved... for the most part. Never realized I'd run into this many problems! Now the only issue is with the actual nlphpmail.php itself. since the submit button has to be named submit, it will not send the form... if only i could switch the results of the if / else statements, then i wouldn't have an issue. I tried it with a very very basic php contact form where i switched out the results of the if / else statements, and my form sent.